# How can i change theme color in bootstrapvue?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I need to change this colors in my bootstrapvue proyect but i don't know how.

primary
secondary
success
info
warning
danger
light
dark

Answer (score 10):

Just read the docs ;) https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/theming/

Just like in normal Bootstrap (without vue) You have all variables in _variables.scss in bootstrap library directory (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss).

You can copy it and modify or make new empty file called ex. variables.scss and import it before You import Bootstrap. Or simply put variables before @import.

```
// Your variable overrides
$body-bg: #000;
$body-color: #111;

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
// BootstrapVue and its default variables
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```

If You need to replace colors it will be:

```
$red: '#ff0000';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was missing this -> @import '../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss' and put "scss" in a style tag.